# Pointing pip to the correct Python interpreter on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have two Python interpreters on my Windows 7 computer: 2.7.6 x64 and 2.7.9 x32. Whenever I use `pip` it installs packages to the 2.7.6 x64 Python interpreter. How can I ask pip to install packages to the other Python interpreter (2.7.9 x32), while still being able to use pip with 2.7.6 x64?

To put it otherwise, I'd like to temporarily point pip to another Python interpreter.

E.g. when installing Python packages shipping as .exe, they give the choice of in which Python interpreter to install them :

[image]

Comment: remove the old pip, download get-pip.py  then python get-pip.py where the python you are using is the interpreter you want to use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I'd like to still the able to use pip with the other Python interpreter. Is there any way to temporarily points pip to the another Python interpreter?

Comment: when you type 'where pip', where is it running from?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman From the  2.7.6 x64 folder.

Comment: is there a pip in the 2.7.9 folder\Scripts? if there is, try running that... if not, then try installing pip into that folder and _then_ running it. one of two things should happen (can't test now): pip either installs into the python it's attached to, or the python that's first on the path. you can control both of those.

Comment: On linux it would be easy just add it to the path first  but not sure on windows.

Comment: on windows: set PATH=c:/new/path;%PATH%. you could put this into two batch files, pip32 and pip64 or something like that.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman There is a pip in the 2.7.9 folder\Script, right now I am switching back and forth, it's not so convenient, I was hoping to use just the same pip and asks it to install for a specific Python interpreter. Good idea for pip32 and pip64, that'd make things a bit better.

Comment: E.g. when installing Python packages shipping as .exe, they give the choice of in which Python interpreter to install them

Comment: The script embedded inside pip.exe is hard coded with a shebang for a particular installation's python.exe, e.g. `#!"C:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe"`.

Comment: Python 3's py.exe launcher lets you run different `major.minor` and `major.minor-32` versions of Python, e.g. `py -2.7-32 -m pip install ...`. With this I never have any system Python installation directory or Scripts directory set in `PATH` -- just virtual environments. The latest version of the launcher that's distributed with 3.5 even defaults to the current virtual environment as a convenience for people accustomed to running `py -x.y -m ...` commands.